# Hibernate Foreign Key Name for ManyToOne with JoinTable

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, foreign-keys, naming

I am not able to get the Foreign Key name set for a `@ManyToOne` relation on `@JoinTable` annotation attribute, it just ignores my setting. I am using Spring-Boot 1.5.4 what used Hibernate 5.0.12.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(
        name                = "PROPERTY_CREDIT_OPTIONS",
        joinColumns         = @JoinColumn(name = "CREDIT_ID", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PROPERTY_CREDIT_OPTIONS_TO_CREDIT"), unique = true),
        inverseJoinColumns  = @JoinColumn(name="PROPERTY_ID", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PROPERTY_CREDIT_OPTIONS_TO_PROPERTY")), 
        foreignKey          = @ForeignKey(name="FK_PROPERTY_CREDIT_OPTIONS_TO_CREDIT"),
        inverseForeignKey   = @ForeignKey(name="FK_PROPERTY_CREDIT_OPTIONS_TO_PROPERTY")
)
@NotNull @NonNull 
Property    property;
```

Outcome:

```
alter table property_credit_options add constraint FKp22j0sq9hexrde9yoyjbj40w2 foreign key (property_id) references property
alter table property_credit_options add constraint FKq8tof33debkfgy0lmp7n5p3we foreign key (credit_id) references not_active_credit
```